# Understanding recursive cte with floats

Tags: mysql, sql, recursive-query, mysql-8.0

I would like to create histograms of some data, but the tool I'm using doesn't have a histogram tool but just a bar chart tool. Therefor I need to fill the gaps and create the bins myself. I'm trying to do this with a recursive cte and a left join (quite new to SQL, so apologies if terminology not on point). I seem to be able to do what I want with integers, but get problems when I move to real numbers.

I have four examples below explained here.

1. Generating a table with with n from 0 to 500 with step size 1 no problem, basically what I want except a table that goes from 0 to 50 with a step size of 0.1.
2. Another table with step size 0.1, from 0 to 9. Works great but not the range I want.
3. As soon as I use n>=10 it doesn't work anymore.
4. In the SELECT statement I use 0, instead of 0.0. Doesn't work.

Questions:

1. How do I generate a table where n has rows from 0 to 50 with step size 0.1?
2. Why do I have to use as many decimals in SELECT x as I want in the steps? For step size of 0.1 I need to enter 0.0 and for 0.01 I need to enter 0.00.

Notes:

- I know a histogram shouldn't really have 501 bins, but the data has
  several interesting parts so it's used to "zoom in" to partical areas.
- I've seen that recursive has a limit of 1 000 rows, but this is below
  that and thus don't understand the errors.

1.Works (returns 501 rows):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 (n) AS
(
  SELECT 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 1 FROM cte1 WHERE n < 500
)
SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

2.Works (returns 91 rows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 (n) AS
(
  SELECT 0.0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 0.1 FROM cte1 WHERE n < 9
)
SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

3.Does not work (reponse `Error Code: 1264. Out of range value for column 'n' at row 1`):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 (n) AS
(
  SELECT 0.0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 0.1 FROM cte1 WHERE n < 10
)
SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

4.Does not work (response `Error Code: 3636. Recursive query aborted after 1001 iterations. Try increasing @@cte_max_recursion_depth to a larger value.`):

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte1 (n) AS
(
  SELECT 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT n + 0.1 FROM cte1 WHERE n < 9
)
SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the docs:

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive
>
> The types of the CTE result columns are inferred from the column types
> of the nonrecursive SELECT part only, and the columns are all
> nullable. For type determination, the recursive SELECT part is
> ignored.

In your case it looks at `SELECT 0.0` and assumes it's `DECIMAL(2,1)` that's why it won't allow more than 1 digit before or after the floating point.

So you need to make a hint to the parser which type you exactly want:

`SELECT CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(3,1))` or `SELECT CAST(0 as float)`

This way it will work.

Hope this answers both your questions.

**Upd.** #4 doesn't work because on each iteration it casts the result as integer and 0 + 0.1 turns into 0.

Comment: Additionally - nonprecise datatype may produce incorrect result. See [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=493104eef7b6de1f5f8d877cd22fdb75), last query.